# IOS Storyboards: Restoration ID just like Storyboard ID?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm using the iBook 'IOS SToryboards' by Steinberg to transition into using storyboards. On page 30, the author's tutorial shows setting the 'Storyboard ID' in the Identity Inspector, to a value - of redScene. In the book graphic this shows as the first field under 'Identify'

In XCode 4.6.1 I don't see 'Storyboard ID', but I do see a field called 'Restoration ID', which I set to the value 'redScene'. I then use that value in the ViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)redButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     UIViewController *redViewController = [[self storyboard]


 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"redScene"];
     [self presentViewController:redViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

However, when I run my app, I get an error right on the line where I refer to 'redScene'. I set an exception breakpoint and I see

(lldb)

I'm not sure what to look at in the values displayed by the debugger on the left side, but I have the idea that probably my code doesn't know who 'redScene' is.

I'm starting to learn to use the apple documentation, but I'm still uncertain about how to locate the right areas to read. I tried searching on both 'restoration id'  and 'storyboard id' there, but I don't get any results.

Did I put enough information into this post?

Thanks for any ideas

Laurel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just played around in the storyboard for a bit, and I think I know your problem! If you select the *view* on the storyboard, it will only let you set the Restoration ID. You need to select the full *view controller*. You can do so by either selecting it in the left hierarchy on the storyboard panel, clicking the status bar on that view controller, or the black bottom bar underneath the view.