# Getting Text field Appium for iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, appium, testcase, appium-ios

I am trying to access the text field of the login page of my app in appium test case. Currently i am using "Restoration Id" to identify the text field and using it as a unique identifier.

Currently appium is not able to find the text field through "Restoration Id" and giving error

```
info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Id selector, 'com.myapps.myappDummyName:id\/loginButton', not found in Localizable.strings.
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElementById('com.myapps.myappDummyName:id\\/loginButton')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementById('com.myapps.myappDummyName:id\/loginButton')
info: [debug] [INST] 2016-05-17 12:54:11 +0000 Debug: Got new command 68 from instruments: au.getElementById('com.myapps.myappDummyName:id\/loginButton')
info: [debug] [INST] 2016-05-17 12:54:11 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementById('com.myapps.myappDummyName:id\/loginButton')
info: [debug] [INST] 2016-05-17 12:54:11 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2016-05-17 12:54:11 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2016-05-17 12:54:11 +0000 Debug: Running system command #69: /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node /Users/Harry/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Condition unmet after 6942ms. Timing out.
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":""},"sessionId":"345b24b8-82da-31da-85c1-45ae33325c15"}
```

Can some one tell how can i get the text field by using the method findElementById() and passing unique id to it. How can i get that id from UITextField in storyboard and where to specify that id in story board.

Comment: what code have you used to access the same? please add that to the question as well

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement textField = driver.findElement(By.id("<resource-id of element>"));
```

This line of code shall let you have an element out of your text field if you specify the id correctly.

To what I can read out of logs :

> info: [debug] Id selector, 'com.myapps.myappDummyName:id/loginButton',
>   not found in Localizable.strings.

You are probably using incorrect `id` string to access the element.

Also, I hope you are not facing this : [IOS Storyboards: Restoration ID just like Storyboard ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825832/ios-storyboards-restoration-id-just-like-storyboard-id)

Comment: What is resource id of any view , how can i get it from story board?

Comment: @AbuzarAmin : try getting it by using `UIAutomator` or `Appium Inspector`

Comment: @AbuzarAmin : if it's ok you have to add  `textField.getText(); ` then print it ;)